# Retrieve Popular Videos In YouTube API V3 Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to get most popular videos or what to watch that is available on the official Youtube application to display in my youtube app that's using Youtube api v3.

I use the following code to search for videos with specific keyword..

```
public List<VideoItem> search(String keywords) {
    query.setQ(keywords);
    try {
        SearchListResponse response = query.execute();
        List<SearchResult> results = response.getItems();

        List<VideoItem> items = new ArrayList<VideoItem>();
        for (SearchResult result : results) {
            String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + result.getId().getVideoId();
            VideoItem item = new VideoItem(result.getSnippet().getTitle(),
                    result.getSnippet().getDescription(), result
                            .getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault()
                            .getUrl(), result.getId().getVideoId(), videoURL);
            items.add(item);
        }
        return items;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("YC", "Could not search: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly.. But I don't know how to get What to Watch to display on my main activity.. I found [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos) but it only works in version 2.. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4):

Using Developers API key for YouTube API V3 use the following to Retrieve Popular Videos In YouTube API V3:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=4
```